# How to versionate artifacts on Artifactory without overwriting

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, versioning

I'm trying to extend our Jenkins job (which builds the entire project) to deploy the built artifacts to our Artifactory but then I faced some problems related to the versioning of the artifacts. If I try to redeploy an artifact whose version didn't change (not a snapshot), I get an error 403 (user 'foo' needs DELETE permission) which is understandable, I should not replace an already released artifact. If the artifact version contains `-SNAPSHOT` then there are no problems, it's always uploaded. My question is: how we should approach the scenario of having locked overwriting in Artifactory?

- Shouldn't the artifactory plugin from Jenkins just ignore the deploy of the artifact in case is already deployed instead of failing the job?
- Or should we use always -SNAPSHOT (during development) even the artifact has not changed?
- Do we increase the version on every release even the artifact has not changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't the artifactory plugin from Jenkins just ignore the deploy
>   of the artifact in case is already deployed instead of failing the
>   job?

The job should fail if the artifact is already deployed with a fixed version (non -SNAPSHOT). For instance on a manual job trigger, I would like to know if I tried to build and deploy using a version name that is already published (maybe by someone else in the team)

> Or should we use always -SNAPSHOT (during development) even the
>   artifact has not changed?

-SNAPSHOT is made for development. Yes we usually push the artifact at the end of the build, even if it did not change because you updated for instance a README and the job was triggered.

Usually SNAPSHOT have a lifetime depending on how you binary repository (here Artifactory) is configured. SNAPSHOT can be cleaned every 2 weeks for instance.

The link shared by Manuel has other interesting definitions like

```
Usually, only the most recently deployed SNAPSHOT,
for a particular version of an artifact is kept in the artifact repository.
Although the repository can be configured to maintain a rolling archive
with a number of the most recent deployments of a given artifact
```

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN401

> Do we increase the version on every release
>   even the artifact has not changed?

yup we increase the version number at every release. I call release what the customer will get. Except an exceptional occasion, you wont go through the process of release if the artifact didn't change. A release usually involves a lot of people in an organization, even people that are not from Development. A popular standard is to use semantic versioning https://semver.org/ Sometime people prefer to version with the date. My advice is to use semver and have a file in the artifact with the date of the build. This file could be used by the artifact itself to tell its version at runtime.

Comment: The versioning we use is `<major>.<minor-non-backward-comp>.<minor-backward-comp>.<hotfix>`. The thing that maybe confused me is that it we do change the version on each release but only the whole "packaging version", not for every artifact. And maybe is right as you say, to increase the version of each artifact on each release even those didn't change.

Comment: Edit: `<major>.<minor>.<don't rember>.<hotfix>`. "Yes we usually push the artifact at the end of the build, even if it did not change because you updated for instance a README and the job was triggered." Exactly, that's the issue. So you propose to push the artifacts manually and not through a jenkins job? That's what I was thinking about too.

Comment: don't bother to change each release version of each artifact, just the one that bundles the package. If you are on git you could tag the artifact (or even all) in order to keep track of what commit was released. Push the artifact though Jenkins. That might seem dumb but all this is about traceability.

Comment: Also, you have to make the distinction between the release that the customer gets and the releases of the artifacts that build it. Indeed, Project Management have their needs, Development have theirs. You don't have to sync all your artifacts on the release the customer gets. But it also depends on which scm you use. Using git, you could tag your packages in order to know where there were released

Comment: The thing is that in our jenkins job, for ease, we build the entire project whenever a commit is pushed in `develop`, so all the artifacts are being built. That's why I asked if it's possible to force jenkins to ignore failures when pushing the artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

You could work with build numbers, and you wouldn't overwrite existing versions. Instead a buildNumber could include some bugfixes/security fixes.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#A1000661

If you're using the depenfency, you can handle the versions with expressions. Exact version or expression which covers the buildNumber.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. The link should just be an example and should give you an orientation